# Simulate a fake directory in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a web app in my local environment that needs to upload some files to a path like `/images/app/customer`. That path does exist on the production server but obviously doesn't on my machine.

Is there a way to "simulate" the existence of that directory on my environment?

Comment: What's wrong with `mkdir -p /images/app/customer` ?

Comment: @MSalters well, I would like to keep my system clean and tidy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question after one year of experiments. It turned out that the best and clean way is to create the directory in a sandboxed environment like Docker or any other virtual machine out there.